# Strange NullPointerException with ListAdapter

Tags: java, android

Okay So I create a ListView and my own `ListAdapter` but whenever I add a result to the `ListAdapter` it crashes saying `NullPointerException`

I do start the `Adaptor` when the `filldata()` is opened `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter ();`

My Code:

```
     public void filldata() throws IOException{
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter ();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

            AdapterItem test = new AdapterItem(1+i, 2+i, 3+i);

            adapter.addAdapterItem(test);
        }

        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<AdapterItem> items;

    public void addAdapterItem(AdapterItem item) {
        items.add(item);
    }

    public int getCount() {
      return items.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
      return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
      View rowView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.searchitemview, parent);
      TextView firstTextView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
      firstTextView.setText(items.get(position).first);
      // do the same with second and third
      return rowView;
    }
}

class AdapterItem {
    public String first;
    public String second;
    public String third;

    public AdapterItem(String first, String second, String third) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
        this.third = third;
    }
}
```

When it gets to `adapter.addAdapterItem(test);` it crashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change here.

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private List<AdapterItem> items=new ArrayList<AdapterItem>();
}
```

You're not instantiating `item` in the `MyAdapter` class.

Answer (score 3):

Initialize `items` in `MyAdapter` constructor. It's `null` when you are trying to add items, hence the exception

```
items = new ArrayList<AdapterItem>();
```